# extracting variables in R using frequencies

Tags: r, data-mining

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
 x  y
 a  1
 b  2
 a  3
 a  4
 b  5
 c  6
 a  7
 d  8
 a  9
 b 10
 e 12
 b 13
 c 15
```

I want to create another dataframe that includes only the `x` values that occur at least 3 times (`a` and `b`, in this case), and their highest corresponding `y` values.

So I want the output as:

```
x   y
a   9
b   13
```

Here `9` and `13` are the highest values of `a` and `b` respectively

I tried using:

```
sort-(table(x,y))
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way, using `subset` to omit any `x` that occur less than 3 times, and then `aggregate` to find the maximum value by group:

```
d <- read.table(text='x y
a 1
b 2
a 3
a 4
b 5
c 6
a 7
d 8
a 9
b 10
e 12
b 13
c 15', header=TRUE)


with(subset(d, x %in% names(which(table(d$x) >= 3))),
     aggregate(list(y=y), list(x=x), max))

#   x  y
# 1 a  9
# 2 b 13
```

And for good measure, a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 3) %>% 
  summarise(max(y))


# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
# 
#    x max(y)
# 1 a      9
# 2 b     13
```

Comment: `aggregate(y ~ x, data=with(dat, dat[ave(y,x,FUN=length)>=3,]), FUN=max)` as an alternative using similar logic.

Comment: @thelatemail - nice, that seems more pleasing to the eye.

Comment: Hey do you know a way i can sort the output to get b first and then a. Since  b is 13 and a is 9

Comment: @Learner27 With `dplyr` you can do `d %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(n() >= 3) %>% summarise(y=max(y)) %>% arrange(desc(y))`. With the `base` R approach it might be easiest to assign first and then reorder do `d2 <- with(subset(d, x %in% names(which(table(d$x) >= 3))), aggregate(list(y=y), list(x=x), max)); d2[order(d2$y, decreasing=TRUE), ]`.

Answer (score 7):

The `data.table` package is great for this.  If `df` is the original data, you can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(y = max(y)[.N >= 3]), by=x]
#    x  y
# 1: a  9
# 2: b 13
```

`.N` is an integer that tells us how many rows are in each group (which we've set to `x` here).  So we just subset `max(y)` such that `.N` is at least three.